# Заменить один текст в HTML-элементах на другой

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var myNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.comp');
    for(var i = 0; i < myNodeList.length; i++) {
     var item = myNodeList[i];
   item.innerHTML.replace(/Нет/g, 'Текст для замены');
   }
```

```html
<div class="comp">Нет</div>
<div class="comp">Нет</div>
<div class="comp">Нет</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.replace` возвращает новую строку:

```
item.textContent = item.textContent.replace(/Нет/g, 'Текст для замены');
```